# how can i get the the class of Datatip?the datatip do not disappear

Tags: apache-flex, datatip

there is a question:

```
public var panelProcess:VBox;
panelProcess = new VBox();
panelProcess.addChild(sf);
panelProcess.setStyle("horizontalAlign","center");
panelProcess.setStyle("verticalAlign","center");
panelProcess.setStyle("backgroundcolor",0xe9e9e9);
panelProcess.buttonMode = true;
panelProcess.useHandCursor = true;
panelProcess.toolTip = "Click to cancel request";
PopUpManager.addPopUp(panelProcess, apc, true); //apc is DisplayObject
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(panelProcess);
```

i create a  PopUpManager on top of the chart when click ChartItem,but i find that the chart's Datatip is topper than the PopUpManager .
when mouseover events on the ChartItem,the Datatip display, then the PopUpManager is created,but the datatip do not disappear，it on top of the PopUpManager ,how can i do?Help!

Answer (score 0):

the DataTip will usualy add to [object _APPNAME_mx_managers_SystemManager]...

1. Extend the DataTip (e.g. MyDataTip)... (in chartView use your DataTipClass -> dataTipRenderer)
2. add a eventlistener FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE
3. what you get is the moment, the dataTip is created and visible...
4. use "this.parent" in the creation_complete handler method... thats the layer where the dataTip is added